# I have reinstalled my PC and lost BitcoinCore, still have the Private Key, can i get my Wallet back?

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key, lost-wallet

so i have reinstalled my PC a few years ago and lost my BitcoinCore Wallet, i still have the PrivateKey.. is there someway to get the Wallet back?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just make a new wallet in BitcoinCore and import your private key using

```
importprivkey <your key here>
```

in the console (Window -> Console, if you are using the GUI).

You may have to rescan the wallet for the funds to become visible (I believe BitcoinCore should generate the address and public key automatically upon import.).

Side note: You should only insert the private key into a system you trust (check the signature of the BitcoinCore client you downloaded) and make sure to encrypt the wallet after you do so. If it is compromised, your funds are gone. Consider keeping it offline at all times if the amount on it is large.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your private key(s) *is* (the important part of) your wallet. See: https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/importprivkey.html

Comment: This answer could be improved by elaborating what the link is for and how to proceed.